# Loop through rows, store columns, paste to new sheet as rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data export that pulls customer info with one row for each parent, and 8 port columns (port1, port2, etc... to port8).  I need to transpose the port columns into a unique record for each port that retains the customer info in the parent.  The source sheet can have 100+ records, the destination sheet will have a maximum of x8 as many records as source sheet because no row has more than 8 ports. I am struggling with how to proceed from here.  My idea was to loop through each SourceData row, build an array for each row that contains all ports field values, transpose this into a new sheet and paste, and continue this until last row.  The struggle is the paste destination must paste in gaps of 8, then the sheet must be filtered so blanks are not present, and then vlookup against the remaining data.

Source Format

[image]
Desired Format

[image]

```
Sub test3()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sourceData As Worksheet
Dim outputData As Worksheet

Set wb = Workbooks("Book1")
Set sourceData = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set outputData = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim Rng As Range
Dim ctr As Long

ctr = 2

Dim iCol As Long, lCol As Long, lRow As Long 'iteration column, last column
Const fCol = 15 'first column

With sourceData
    lCol = 22 'last used column
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row
    
    
    For i = 2 To lRow
        
        For iCol = fCol To lCol
        Set Rng = Cells(i, iCol)
        
    
        
        outputData.Cells(ctr, fCol).Value = Rng
        ctr = ctr + 1
        
        
    
        Next iCol
    Next i
    

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 2**: updated to include extra rows as output.

Lightly tested...

```vb
Sub test3()

    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, srcData, outData, r As Long
    Dim c As Long, rOut As Long, p As Long, prt
    
    'get input data as array
    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    srcData = wsSrc.Range("A2:W" & wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    'size output array to max potential size (+ added some space for pepwave/remote cases)
    ReDim outData(1 To 10 * UBound(srcData, 1), 1 To 16)
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(srcData, 1)      'loop input data rows
        For p = 1 To 8                   'loop ports
            prt = srcData(r, 14 + p)
            If Len(prt) > 0 Then         'if any port value...
                rOut = rOut + 1          'add output row
                For c = 1 To 14          'populate common columns
                    outData(rOut, c) = srcData(r, c)
                Next c
                outData(rOut, 15) = prt  'add port value
                outData(rOut, 16) = srcData(r, 23) 'col W value
            End If
        Next p
        
        'test to see if we're adding additional rows...
        If InStr(1, srcData(r, 6), "pepwave", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            rOut = rOut + 1
            'populate pepwave row from srcdata (r,x)
        End If
        If InStr(1, srcData(r, 6), "data remote", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            rOut = rOut + 1
            'populate data remote row from srcdata (r,x)
        End If
        'done testing for additional rows
    Next r
    
    If rOut > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Resize(rOut, UBound(outData, 2)).Value = outData
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: this code has worked perfect to satisfy my request.  However, I would like to adjust it to pull in column W, which is the next column to the right of port8 (the last port column you helped me return in the array).  How can I do this?

Comment: I can get column W into the array and stored, I just don't know how to get it back out of the array and into the destination sheet.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams, I have been using your code but failing to accomplish one thing.  To explain, one condition is that src column F contains the term "Pepwave" and the other is that it contains the term "Data Remote".  Image for clarification - https://imgur.com/a/ekfxeqa.  Given the source row contains 'Pepwave', I need and additional single row inserted for that ticket ID in the destination sheet that contains source data in columns [A-F], L, M, and W.  Given it contains 'Data Remote', I do not insert a row and I use source data in G, H, & I instead of L & M.  I'm not sure if this makes sense.

Comment: See above - that will give you a start on adding the extra rows.

Comment: Is there a way to deal with scientific notation that comes through in destination column J?  It cuts my numbers off after 15 digits by appending 0's for the remaining digits.

Comment: Excel can only handle numbers up to 15 digits of precision - if you have numeric data with more than 15 digits then you need to format those cells as Text *before* the data is populated.  That does mean you need to address that for your source data first...

Comment: I can take what you've given and finish what I am working on.  You have helped me immensely and I can't thank you enough!  Provide me a way and I'll buy you a six pack.

Comment: How would I resize this to accept 3 additional fields?  Currently I have the full Service Address in one column, but the output will now be separating that into Address, City, State, Zip.  I struggle to make sense out of this code if I'm being honest.

Comment: It would be easier to dump the existing output onto a worksheet and then split the address into 4 fields.

Comment: This is what I currently do, but the data entry folks screw up the format a lot, which requires me to manually fix addresses that don't get split correctly.  If they split the field into 4, can I simply resize the array?

Comment: Yes just resize to add 3 extra columns to `srcData` and `outData`